# JSON request to Node.js

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I am passing a JSON object like

```
[{"name":"SHIFT"},{"name":"CONVERSION"},{"name":"VARIATION"}]
```

and `POST` request is

```
 $.ajax({
    url: 'myUrl',
    type:'POST',
    dataType: "json",
    cache: false,
    timeout: 5000,
    data:json,//passing a json obj
     success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) { alert("success") },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.log(jqXHR);
    }
 });
```

I am using express within my Node module and below is my node.js code

```
var express = require('express');
var  http = require('http');
var path = require('path');
var app=express();
var app=express.createServer();
app.use(express.bodyParser());
app.use(app.router);

  app.post("/",function(request,response) {              
     console.log(request);  
     response.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', "*");
     console.log(request.body)
    // response.send(request.body); 
 });
```

How do I get the JSON string and parse it in `app.post` method ?  I tried request.body but  it provides me with the following

```
{"SHIFT":"","CONVERSION":"","VARIATION":""}
```

Comment: See this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11994829/node-js-parse-json-of-request and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10005939/how-to-consume-json-post-data-in-an-express-application

Comment: I have already referred it, but still i am getting the same response.

Comment: Please post how you pass the json object. $.ajax({ data:json,//passing a json obj });

Comment: json is a variable that I have used. var json=[{"name":"SHIFT"},{"name":"CONVERSION"},{"name":"VARIATION"}]

Comment: That isn't JSON, that is an array of objects. Wrap it in a `JSON.stringify();`

Comment: @Kevin. i wrapped up in the array of objects ie [{"name":"SHIFT"},{"name":"CONVERSION"},{"name":"VARIATION"} in JSON.stringify().How do I parse it in node.js level once i do the post request.?

Comment: `var data = JSON.parse(request.body);`

Comment: @KevinReilly when i do console.log in node.js for request.body, it is null.

Comment: You should be able to inspect the request on the client side to see what the client is sending (IE: Network tab in developer tools). I think on the jquery side you might need to set a header saying the content type is application/json. You might also want to `console.log(request);` for fun.

Comment: I now see what the problem is. The `data` key of `$.ajax` is, by default, used for a simple query string like `foo=bar&beep=boop`. If you make your array of objects into an object of key-vale pairs, it should work properly without JSON.

Comment: @KevinReilly, yes I have thought about this. but the issue for me is i have to populate the array in an each fucntion, which populates json.push({name:$(this).text()});.AFter which i have done JSON.stringify(json).

Answer (score 0):

```
 $.ajax({
    url: 'myUrl',
    type:'POST',
    dataType: "json",
    cache: false,
    timeout: 5000,
    data:{
    jsonData: "{ \"name\": \"SHIFT\", \"name\": \"CONVERSION\",\"name\": \"VARIATION\" }"
    // or jsonData: JSON.stringify(credentials)   (newest browsers only)
    },
     success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) { alert("success") },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.log(jqXHR);
    }
 });
```

Comment: how do i get this format of json string.  I have a div and I want all the contents of div to be inserted in a json object                       $("div ol li span[class=title]").each(function (e)
  {
     //var arr={};
     //arr["name"]=$(this).text();
     //jsonStr.push(arr);
     jsonStr.push({name:$(this).text()});
     
  });
    var json = JSON.stringify(jsonStr);

Comment: var temp = new Object();
temp["name"] =$(this).text();  jsonStr.push(temp);